# 2D Graphics Transform - moving the origin

Tags: c#, 2d, transform, .emf, metafile

I have a vector graphics format that has its origin at the bottom left and i need to render it to an enhanced metafile which has its origin at the top left. What is a transform to move between the two without flipping it upside down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question completely, but here goes: Create a vector from the old origin to the new origin (a vector pointing upwards) and subtract that from all points in the file.

If you want to do this as a transform, you need a 3 by 3 matrix like the following:

1  0  0

0  1  -T

0  0  1

Where "T" is the translation required from top to bottom..

hope thats usefull to you...